# touchpad & keyboard not working ubuntu 18.04 lenovo n22

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, lenovo, laptop

I have a Lenovo n22 laptop running ubuntu 18.04. I grabbed the laptop & pressed the space bar to bring it out of hibernation. I'm not sure exactly what happened after but the keyboard and touchpad stopped working.

I tried <kbd>F6</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd> without success with a keyboard connected via USB.

I followed this advice and still hasnt made a difference...

```
sudo apt update                   
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics  
sudo apt update  
sudo apt autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all && sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-all  
sudo apt update
```

I also booted into a live cd without success.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with a Lenovo Flex 3-1130, the only way to make them work again is to boot with an older kernel (4.15.0.29 instead of 4.15.0.139).
It seems to be an ACPI/IRQ handling issue.